# RegExp - replace quote doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

I would like to replace variable `str'` with `<span class="red">str'</span>`, but I always get the `"'"` outeside of the span. I wrote the following javascript:

```
var f1="XY+X'Y";
var str=X;
var patt=new RegExp(str+'\'',"g");
f1.replace(patt, "<span class=\"red\">"+str+"'"+"</span>")
```

I get:

```
<span class="red">X</span>';
```

I want:

```
<span class="red">X'</span>;
```

Comment: is `var f1=XY+X'Y` supposed to be `var f1="XY+X'Y"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for "X'" in your regex, and replacing it with `<span ...>X''</span>` as far as I can see. There appear to be a few issues with your code, and I'm not sure how you expect to get either result (the one you get, or the one you want) from the given code. May I suggest this alternative?

```
var f1="XY+X'Y";
var str="X";
var patt=new RegExp(str+"\'?","g");
f1.replace(patt, "<span class=\"red\">$&</span>")
```

This will find X **or** X' in the source and surround it with the red class span. If you only want to highlight X', then take out the `?` in the patt variable (the ? makes the apostrophe optional).

Edit:

Soluction:

The problem was that I use replace twice on the same string. Something like this

```
var str =f1.replace(patt, "<span class=\"red\">"+str+"</span>").f1.replace(patt, "<span class=\"red\">"+str+"'"+"</span>")
```

this works for me:

```
var str =f1.replace(patt, "<span class=\"red\">"+str+"</span>");
var str2=str.replace(patt, "<span class=\"red\">"+str+"'"+"</span>");
```

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

When I evaluate

```
var f1="XY+X'Y";
var str="X";
var patt=new RegExp(str+'\'',"g");
f1.replace(patt, "<span class=\"red\">"+str+"'"+"</span>")
```

I get

```
"XY+<span class="red">X'</span>Y"
```

Which I think is your intended result? Maybe you just need to double check your quotes/string variables?